# Nested React router 4 routes not working on Webpack 3

Tags: webpack, react-router, webpack-dev-server, html-webpack-plugin

As the tittle suggest i can't get routes like

```
<Route path="/events/:id" component={EventDetailRoute} />
```

to work, and as i've read seems to be that the bundle in the index.html must be absolute, however i'm **using the HtmlWebpackPlugin** so the bundle gets injected as a relative path.

I've tried to set my output config for webpack as follows:

```
output: {
    path: path.resolve('dist'),
    filename: 'index_bundle.js',
    publicPath: '/'
},
```

But that doesn't work neither.

If i try this route: *http://localhost:8080/events/7*, I'm **getting a 404 error** when trying to find *http://localhost:8080/events/index_bundle.js*

This is my **webpack.config**:

```
const path = require('path'),
    HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin'),
    webpack = require('webpack');

const HtmlWebpackPluginConfig = new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
    template: './src/index.html',
    filename: 'index.html',
    inject: 'body'
})

module.exports = {
    entry: './src/index.js',
    output: {
        path: "/" + path.resolve('dist', 'build'),
        filename: 'index_bundle.js',
        publicPath: '/'
    },
    devServer: {
        historyApiFallback: true,
        hot: true,
        publicPath: '/'
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.jsx?$/,
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                exclude: /node_modules/
            },
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: 'style-loader'
                    },
                    {
                        loader: 'css-loader',
                        options: {
                            modules: true,
                            camelCase: 'dashes',
                            localIdentName: '[name]__[local]'
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        loader: 'resolve-url-loader'
                    },
                    {
                        loader: 'sass-loader'
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: [
                    { loader: 'style-loader' },
                    { loader: 'css-loader' },
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.(eot|svg|ttf|woff|woff2)$/,
                use: {
                    loader: 'file-loader?name=[name].[ext]&outputPath=fonts/',
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.(png|jpg)$/,
                use: {
                    loader: 'file-loader?name=[name].[ext]&outputPath=assets/',
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        HtmlWebpackPluginConfig,
        new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
        new webpack.NamedModulesPlugin()
    ]
}
```

Im using webpack 3.1.0, webpack-dev-server 2.5.1 and react-router-dom 4.1.1

Comment: can you describe what you mean by doesn't work? What happens when you load the `/` and use a `<Link to="events/2"  />`

Comment: @azium i've edited the question to add more details about the error

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Add `<base href="/" />` to head tag of your index.html file

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>React App Setup</title>
    <base href="/" />
</head>
```

Comment: live saving advise. Thank you

Comment: Best, You save my time. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Can you please briefly explain the answer? Why it was failing, and what this line does to resolve the issue?

Comment: Works, but how. Can anyone elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

I tried the `<base href="/" />` solution. It worked for my bundle file but not my css. Then, I noticed the real problem. Both of my paths were relative, so the reload caused them to load at the wrong path.

#### Solution

```
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/index.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app"></div>
    <script src="/bundle.js"></script>
  </body>
```

Notice, the non-relative paths `/index.css` and `/bundle.js`. Before, they were `./index.css` and `./bundle.js`.