# HistoryApiFallback not working on Webpack 4 (with React Router 4 and nested routes)

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-dev-server, react-router-v4

Context: 
Trying out RR4 with webpack 4 (devServer: {apiHistoryFallback: true}
[Sample Webpack 4 config](https://gist.github.com/thomasgwatson/a60e973207ff9387f68adfe2426755b8)

http://localhost:8080/reports works when cut and pasted into the address bar (aka history fallback is working)
and I can click a link for /reports/8, as I have added a nested route to the component at /reports

`<Route path=${match.path}/:reportId component={ReportDetail}/>`

but cut and paste http://localhost:8080/reports/9 into the address bar and I get a blank screen and a:
`Refused to execute script from 'http://localhost:8080/reports/main.js' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.`
Tried setting the contentBase for devServer but that didn't resolve the issue.

This functionality worked fine in Webpack 3 and RR3. Not sure whether to bark up the Webpack or React Router tree.

[Similar issue to this one but for Webpack 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49760641/refused-to-execute-script-from-because-its-mime-type-text-html-is-not-execut)

Answer (score 5):

Apparently adding:

`<base href="/" />`

to the head tag of your `index.html` is enough to fix this issue. Meep

Answer (score 1):

I found out that if you add:

```
output: {
  publicPath: '/' 
}
```

to your webpack.config.js then you don't need to add

```
<base href="/" />
```

to index.html

see: [webpack-dev-server, historyApiFallback not working (webpack-4, react-router-4)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53387756/webpack-dev-server-historyapifallback-not-working-webpack-4-react-router-4)