# React routing will not refresh after I add paths to url

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I am using react v16 and react-router-dom v4 and I already have my routes working for the most part. I am using webpack-dev-server to run my dev environment and when I refresh or manually type in a url for the react app it will work fine most of the time. My problem is that when I start adding url paths to the routes, then the refresh and manual url typing will no longer work.

A quick example:

```
<Router>
    <Root>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path='/' component={Welcome} />
        <Route path='/home' component={Home} />
        <Route path='/profile/:id' component={Profile} />
        <Route path='/profile/dashboard' component={Dashboard} />
        <Redirect to='/' />
      </Switch>
    </Root>
</Router>
```

In this instance, I currently can navigate wherever I want when I begin from the start of the app, refreshing works for "/home" and "/" routes too. The only problem is with the routes with the extra path. If I were to navigate to "/profile/dashboard" and refresh, I will get a bunch of 404 errors saying that all the static links are broken. It seems like webpack is now redirecting to a /profile/ folder that isn't there. How can I fix this? Is this a problem with my react-router-dom setup or my webpack setup?

Here is my webpack config for my dev environment as well. I call it with `--history-api-fallback`

```
module.exports = {
  devServer: {
    inline: true,
    contentBase: './',
      port: 4200
  },
  devtool: 'cheap-module-eval-source-map',
  entry: './index.js',
  mode: 'development',
  module: {
      loaders: [
          {
              test: /\.js$/,
              loaders: ['babel'],
              exclude: /node_modules/
          },
          {
              test: /\.scss/,
              loader: 'style-loader!css-loader!sass-loader'
          }
      ]
  },
  output: {
      path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
      filename: 'bundle.min.js'
  },
  plugins: [
      new webpack.optimize.OccurrenceOrderPlugin(),
      new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        template: './index.html'
    })
  ]
};
```

Comment: Note: due to your route ordering, the url `/profile/dashboard` will match your `/profile/:id` route and hence use the component `Profile`.  You likely want to put `/profile/dashboard` above `/profile/:id` in your `<Switch>`.

Comment: You're right, I know this. This was just a quick example trying to demonstrate my issue.  I could put the "exact" prop on a route to ensure it doesn't give a false positive there. Or I could reorder, like you said.

Answer (score 3):

I finally found the answer and it is simple.  Credit has to go to the answer from another question since this seems to be duplicate of
[Nested Routes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45133342/nested-react-router-4-routes-not-working-on-webpack-3?rq=1)

I just could not search it easily. After adding `<base href="/" />` to my index.html the problem went away. I should have known it since the resources were trying to link to somewhere other than the root folder.

Comment: This solution work for me, but do you know the reason? Why we should adding `<base href="/" />` to index.html and why the trouble is solved?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you've done anything wrong - but I think you'll need to set up the server to load your index.html file regardless of what url is requested.

When you use the history API, it isn't actually hitting `/profile/dashboard`, but when you load that direct from the address bar, it is looking for `/profile/dashboard` on the server (as I'm sure you know from your question).

When you run webpack dev server, are you just calling `yarn run webpack-dev-derver --history-api-fallback`? If you are, perhaps the option is being passed to the yarn run command, I think you can make sure that the `--history-api-fallback` param is applied to the command being run by running `yarn run webpack-dev-derver -- --history-api-fallback`

You could modify `webpack-dev-server` to include https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserver-historyapifallback as well, to see if that works.

For production, something like this https://gist.github.com/RaVbaker/2254618 in htaccess might help, although I haven't tested anything so it's a slight punt on whether that will solve your issue.

Comment: my script that I have running the command is something like `webpack-dev-server --history-api-fallback` I know that it was being applied correctly since I could refresh on say, a signup page, and it would correctly come back to signup.  I have also just tried using the fallback api inside the webpack config file itself to no success. My only issue is that refresh will not work after I add another path fragment.  "/profile/" for example.

Comment: AH - I see you've solved it - but this might shed more light on it - using an absolute path in your webpack config might also have worked: https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server/issues/216

i.e.

`devServer: {
    inline: true,
    contentBase: '/',
      port: 4200
  },`