# react router dom 6^. Unable to route Dynamically

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-router-dom

I am having trouble with dynamic routing in
react-router-dom.

Whenever I go to the dynamic page I get a white screen. Only error message is

The resource from  localhost:8082/individuals/bundle.js was blocked due to MIME type(“text/html”) mismatch (X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff).

I have research countless articles and have been unable to find a solution.
Every Other static Component Works and is able to pull from the api.

The API I am pulling from is able to dynamically display products.
`"http://localhost/40"` 
will display the object with the id of 40 in json format. `Node.js express Api`

Thank you for your time
Route Component

```js
function Rout(){
  
  
    return(
      
      <div>
        <BrowserRouter>
        
        <Menu/>
        <div className="page">
        <Routes>
          <Route index element={<MainContent />} />

          <Route path="/products" element={<Product />} />
          
          <Route path='/individuals/:id' element={<Individualproduct />} />
           
          <Route path="/about/" exact element={<About />} />

          <Route path="/shippingandreturns" element={<Shipping />} />
        </Routes>
        </div>
        </BrowserRouter>
        </div>
    )
}
export default Rout
```

Dynamic Component

```js
const Individualproduct = () => {
  const { id } = useParams();
  const [products, setProducts] = useState([]);
    const url = 'http://192.168.1.91:4001/';
    useEffect(()=>{
        async function getProduct(){
            const response = await axios.get(`${url}/${id}`);
            const a = (response.data.Results)
            console.log(a)
            setProducts(a)
        }
        getProduct()
    }, [])
  return (
    <article>
    
        {
            products.map((item)=>{
                <h1>{item.id}</h1>
            })
        }
            
        
    
      
    </article>
  );
};
```

Comment: Could it be that not dynamic content is the problem, but multi-level routing in general? Try `<Route path='/individuals/item1' ... />`. If that's the case, this might be related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72869447/react-routing-how-to-create-multi-level-routing

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Nested React router 4 routes not working on Webpack 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45133342/nested-react-router-4-routes-not-working-on-webpack-3)